# i can't install express in my package.json file in termux

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install, termux

```
I tried <code> npm install --save express </code> to install express in my package.json file and it gave me
```

`/storage/emulated/0/swifttest
$ npm install --save express
npm WARN swifttest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN swifttest@1.0.0 No repository field.`

npm ERR! path ../express
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../express' -> '/storage/emulated/0/swifttest/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../express' -> '/storage/emulated/0/swifttest/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../express' -> '/storage/emulated/0/swifttest/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../express',

I know it has to do with permission but i dont know my way around. I use Android 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Run your `npm install` as root I.e `sudo npm install --save express`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i did it. I figured i went through emulated instead of termux directory. I used data/data/files/home as against emulated i used earlier

Answer (score 0):

`npm i express -D --no-bin-links`
For symlink errors
Ik this post is really old but it may help others in the future who see this